# JavaFx: Смена одного окна на другое

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть такой код:

```
    @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));


    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Как мне сделать так что бы из совершенно отдельного класса controller заменить main.fxml на server.fxml и соответственно показать его?

Comment: Передавайте имя fxml отдельным параметром

Comment: @Alex78191 Да, это вполне может помочь, но как получить доступ к primaryStage из другого класса, что бы заменить сцену?

Comment: передавай текущую stage

Comment: @Alex78191 а не подскажите как это сделать? я пробовал, но я явно где то ошибся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил я проблему проще
В Main классе создал отдельный Stage и сделал его ссылкой на основной stage

```
public Stage MainStage;
MainStage = primaryStage;
```

А в контроллер

```
@FXML
public static Stage STAGE;
public void serverMethod(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("server.fxml"));
    STAGE.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
    Server s = new Server();
    s.startServer();
}
```

Это один из самых простых вариантов.

UPD: Обязательно создавайте отдельный контроллер, к сожалению использовать один контроллер на несколько fxml нельзя. Также, если нужно что бы запустился какой то код, при замены сцены, то пользуйтесь `initialize`.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим так:

```
public void onNewOrder(){
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/Order/OrderNew.fxml"));
        Parent page = loader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(page));
        WeakReference<OrderNewController> newOrd = new WeakReference<OrderNewController>(loader.getController());
        newOrd.get().setStage(stage);
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Соответсвенно в классе OrderNewController создан сеттер для Stage и далее он в нем используется. Так же можно через какой нибудь свой класс реализующий SharedPreference передавать.

Для примера в контролллере обрабатываем закрытие окна:

```
  public void setStage(Stage stage) {
        this.stage=stage;
        this.stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            public void handle(WindowEvent we) {
                //обработка
            }
        });
    }
```

Ну и в fxml не забыть явно определить контроллер.